# route override the controller route with

Tags: laravel, tabs, routes, laravel-blade, laravel-5

so im trying to pass a variable to my view, but i don't know how the default route in routes.php override the with variable..
let me be more specific
in my view welcome i have a tab-content with 4 tabs (login, register, contact, and home (the apresentacion text) ) and when the user fails the login for example when redirect he goes always for the home tab because is the active tab.
im trying to pass the name of the tab i want to make that the active tab.
so..

In my controller

[login method]

```
(...)
if (Auth::attempt($credentials, true))
   return redirect()->route('choice');
return redirect()->route('index')
   ->with('tab','login')
   ->withInput();
```

[register method]

```
(code)
return redirect()->route('index')
       ->with('tab','register')
       ->withInput();
```

In the view [tab code]

```
{{ isset($tab) ? '' : $tab='home' }}

<div class="tab-content">
   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane content {{ $tab=='home' ? 'active' : '' }}" id="home"></div>
   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane content {{ $tab=='login' ? 'active' : '' }}" id="login"></div>
   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane content {{ $tab=='register' ? 'active' : '' }}" id="register"></div>
   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane content {{ $tab=='contact' ? 'active' : '' }}" id="contact"></div>
</div>
```

Routes.php [is in the web group]

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
})->name('index');
```

i already try to change the return redirect to return view but dont work and already dd($tab) but always empty

i think is because the routes.php but not sure...
srry for the english guys, and ty for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you use `return redirect()->route('index')->with('tab','login')` the data is flashed to the session. To get the data in your view you use `{{ session('tab') }}`. More info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

Comment: same thing like the other anwser..
edited post, same view for the diferent tabs ..